# Visual Prolog: Checking if integer* list head is even or odd

Tags: prolog

I want to check, if a head of an integer* list is even or odd

I use the mod operator, but the program throws an error

error c504 : The expression has type '::integer*', which is incompatible with the type '::integer'

As I understand it, the Head is a list, that contains a single element, but I have no idea how to extract it to use in an integer operator

```
Function([Head | Tail], [Head | TailEven], OddList) :-
        0 = Head mod 2,%<- The problem is here
        append(Head, TailEven, EvenList),
        Function(Tail, EvenList, OddList).
```

I've tried to create a sum predicate, that sums up all list elements, but the sum term still needs to be integer*, which defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: Use: `0 is Head mod 2`, because it's arithmetic rather than unification. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2

Comment: This doesn't work, because I use Visual Prolog, not SWI Prolog.
If this is used, the following error is shown:
error c161 : Syntax error: 'in' is expected

Comment: It seems that an error occured somewhere in the IDE, as I have closed it and it worked fine after the restart.